# Trouble Replacing Null Values in RSQLite Query

Tags: python, sql, r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm querying a database to create a data-frame for graphing and one of my data transformations requires a mathematical operation so I need the null entries of a particular column to be zeroes instead. However, I can't get the null values to replace.

Here's a sample output versus an expected output:

```
Actual:
  income travel_spending sports_leisure_spending gender percent_travel
1     25              33                      NA      M     1.32000000
2    357             136                      NA      M     0.38095238
3     25              18                       5      M     0.72000000
4     51             527                      NA      M    10.33333333
5     51             527                      NA      F    10.33333333
6     48               4                      60      F     0.08333333

Expected:
  income travel_spending sports_leisure_spending gender percent_travel
1     25              33                       0      M     1.32000000
2    357             136                       0      M     0.38095238
3     25              18                       5      M     0.72000000
4     51             527                       0      M    10.33333333
5     51             527                       0      F    10.33333333
6     48               4                      60      F     0.08333333
```

Here's my code. The column in question is sports_leisure_spending:

```
query <- 'SELECT income, REPLACE(travel_spending, "33", "33") AS travel_spending, 
    CASE sports_leisure_spending WHEN "NA" THEN "0" ELSE sports_leisure_spending END AS sports_leisure_spending, 
    gender, CAST(travel_spending AS float)/CAST(income AS float) AS percent_travel FROM customer'
```

I've also attempted the following:

```
REPLACE(sports_leisure_spending, "NA", "0") -> does nothing
REPLACE(sports_leisure_spending, NA, "0") -> does nothing
REPLACE(sports_leisure_spending, NULL, "0") -> makes EVERYTHING NA
REPLACE(sports_leisure_spending, "", "0") -> does nothing
```

Comment: can you try `when NULL then 0 else ...` treat it as numeric

Comment: "0" is not a number

Comment: Tested it, doesn't do anything